# .class specific search and replace

Tags: notepad++, html, sublime-text-2

I'm trying to remove entire tag with specific class:

**Code:**

```
<div> 
Blah blah 
<div class='myClass'>
  <div>some other div</div>
</div>
</div>

<div> 
Blah blah 
<div class='myClass'>
  more text
</div>
</div>

<div> 
Blah blah 
<div class='myClass'>
  more text
</div>
</div>
```

I want to search for .myClass tag and replace it with "" (delete) 
**so the Result is:**

```
<div> 
Blah blah 

</div>

<div> 
Blah blah 

</div>

<div> 
Blah blah 

</div>
```

I know it's easy with jQuery but I want to do it on the text editor side.
Or maybe I can just view code and copy it after jquery has deleted it.
Sublime Text or Notepad++

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use notepad++ with regular expressions

1. Open Notepadd++
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
3. Select *Regular expression* as search mode
4. Enter `^.*myClass.*$` under *Find* what and nothing under *Replace with*
5. Click *Replace all*

[image]

---

### Cases where start and end strings are in different lines (Notepad 6.xx)

We use a workaround and temporary delete all carriage returns (+newlines).
This gives us a single long line where its much easier to use RegEx. Later we put the carriage returns back.

1. Choose a unique string like `%%%NEWLINE%%%` which doesn't occur so far in your text.
   Test it first with a simple <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and select *Regular expression* as search mode
3. Find `\r\n` and replace with `%%%NEWLINE%%%`. Click *Replace all*.
   `\r\n` are special characters and stand for *carriage return* and *newline*. You get one long line.
   Remember: From now on you can't use `^` and `$` anymore
4. Find `<div .*?myClass.*?</div>` and replace with nothing (Notice the space)
5. Find `%%%NEWLINE%%%` and replace with `\r\n` to bring back our normal text structure

While writing my edit I noticed you have changed your question with a game breaker. This method (probably no RegEx method at all) won't work while you have nested `<div></div>` tags. The RegEx engine can't know if it should stop at the 2nd, 3th or n-th `</div>`

#### [Used RegEx](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

```
^  → line beginning
.  → any single character
*  → repeat previous pattern 
.*  → any characters as long as possible (greedy)  
.*? → any characters as short as possible (non greedy)
$  → line end
```

#### Used resources

- http://markantoniou.blogspot.de/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html
- http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Searching
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398613/notepad-newline-in-regex

Comment: Works great on one line. I failed to propery simplify the example. Sorry. I've edited it so the closing </div> is on a different line.

Comment: Your last edit gave me some headache. Nested `<div>` tags are a problem for my RegEx method.

Comment: Sorry abou that :) You went above and beyond! I really think text editors should have a function or plugin for selecting html tags and classes (non-RegEx based :) ).

Comment: For a single operation, there is a notepad++ plugin called [HTML tag](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/HTMLTag/). Here is a [example picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9cWQP.png). This only helps to identify a closing tag. Nothing more, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I still use Dreamweaver mostly because its "specific tag" search. You can find, remove, strip and change everything easily. On your case you can find every `div` tag that has `myClass` class and remove tag with content. It only takes 5 sec to have your wanted result.

You can see how it works on this link http://www.lehigh.edu/computing/web/IntDreamweaver/find.html

This is the most important missing part on notepad++ for my needs.