# How to keep special strings in notepad++ and delete other strings?

Tags: notepad++

I want to find some special strings in my text and then delete other strings.

For example in this sentence:

```
( (IP-MAT (CONJ vnnd)
      (NP-NOM (D das) (N wort))
      (BED war)
      (PP (P bey)
          (CODE [2])
          (NP-DAT (NPR Gott)))
      (. ,))
```

I want to regularly keep: `CONJ D N BED P NPR`. 
and delete other strings in this text.

Second example:

```
( (IP-MAT-SPE (NP-NOM-LFD (D diser) (NPR Jhesus)
 (, ,)
 (CP-REL-SPE (WNP-1 (WPRO wilcher)) (C 0)
 (IP-SUB-SPE (NP-NOM T-1) (PP (P von) (NP-DAT (PRO euch))) (BEPI ist) (RP auff) (VAN genomen) (PP (P gen) 
 (NP-ACC-XXX (NPR hymel)))))) 
 (, ,) 
 (NP-NOM-RSP (D der)) (RDPI wirt) (VB komen)
(PP (P wie) (CP-ADV-SPE (C 0) (IP-SUB-SPE (NP-NOM (PRO yhr)) (NP-ACC-2 (PRO yhn)) (VBN gesehen) (HVPI habt) 
(IP-INF-SPE (NP-ACC-SBJ ICH-2) (PP (P gen)
(NP-ACC-XXX (NPR hymel))) (VB faren)))))
 (. .))
```

and I want to change them to this :

```
D NPR , WPRO C NP-NOM P PRO BEPI RP VAN P NPR , D RDPI VB , P C PRO PRO VBN HVPI NP-ACC-SBJ P NPR VB . –
```

Comment: What would you like the result to look like?  Please edit this question and provide an example result.

Comment: Jerry edited it. This example is about Corpora that we want to normalize them. It is not related to computer subject. But Our end is separate some strings and delete others.

Comment: @user259288 You can edit it back if you want. If I understand correctly, you just want to get `CONJ D N BED P NPR` on a single line, right?

Comment: @Jerry Yes exactly.

Comment: @user259288 Do you have more examples perhaps? Just in case there's one solution which works only for what you've provided and not your full file. If possible, try to get one which is very different from what you have currently in your question.

Comment: @user259288 Could you put those in your question by [editing](http://superuser.com/posts/653417/edit) it? You can then delete those comments. It's difficult to understand the structure that way =P

Comment: Thank you for editing  .I think I have to believe there is no way except separating these tags manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, sounds like you can do something like this:

Find:

```
(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))*?\(([\w,.-]+)\s+[\w,.-]+\)+|(?:(?!\n\n).(?<!\n\n))+$
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

[Dollar, then "1", then space]

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zA2aU0)

Try to get one of the latest notepad++ versions if this doesn't work and make sure you checked 'regular expressions' in the Search&Replace dialog box and checked '. match newlines'.

Comment: Can you get rid of `\n` if you first [convert multiline to single line, do the regex and finally convert back from single line to multiline?](http://superuser.com/questions/622844/class-specific-search-and-replace/622845#622845)

Comment: @nixda Hmm, I would rather not. It will make the `.` match those replaced strings and this would prevent keeping the 'paragraphs' (if I can call them like that) separate. Interesting answer you had there though :)

Comment: @Jerry Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @user259288 What happens exactly? Nothing, error, or wrong replace?

Comment: @Jerry  Oh..sorry I forgot space. It works! Thank you Jerry.I'm so surprised :)

Comment: @user259288 Okay, that's awesome then! n_nb

Comment: @Jerry Hi Jerry. This code don't work for some sentences. It deleted some other important tags such like pro$. could you help me?It's so necessary for me. please .